# Image upload on linux server (PHP)

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to upload image to server. The following code works when I use on local pc but when I try on server, image is not uploaded.

```
$img = $_FILES['file_uploaded']['name'];
$image_temp = $_FILES['file_uploaded']['tmp_name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($image_temp, "uploads/" . $img)){
    $fullpath =  dirname(__FILE__) . '\\images\\' . $img;
}
else
    echo 'Failed!';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the same file permissions on server? Does folder `/var/www/html/uploaded` exist and is writable by web server user (usually www-data)?

Try running following command in server terminal:

```
sudo su
mkdir /var/www/html/uploads
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/uploads
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/uploads
```

Where www-data is used, change it with your own web server user.

**"FIXED" SCRIPT:**

```
$img = $_FILES['file_uploaded']['name'];
$upload_dir = "/var/www/html/uploads/";
$image_temp = $_FILES['file_uploaded']['tmp_name'];
if (file_exists($image_temp)) {
     echo "Temp file doesn't exist.";
     return false;
}
$move_file = move_uploaded_file($image_temp, $upload_dir . $img);
if ($move_file) {
    $fullpath =  $upload_dir . $img;
}
else {
    echo 'Failed!';
    return false;
}
```

You should write additional checks, so you know where your application fails.

Regarding security, you should never trust user. In this case we used filename (`$_FILES['file_uploaded']['name']`)provided by user, using which he could write and maybe even read outside of designated directory

Comment: Hi, Sigismund, I want to know if my syntax is right or not ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't really check the syntax.
Yea it isn't really right. You are using move_uploaded_file twice, you should probably use it just once. The paths used for copying are also all wrong.
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is prepended to /var/www... ?

Comment: actually I want to upload image in root/var/www/html/uploads folder.

Comment: Check this site: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php. DOCUMENT_ROOT will give you the path to the folder where current script is executed, you should remove it from your script or use it like this `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT' ]. "uploads/`if your script is located in /var/www/html

Comment: index.php is located in /var/www/html and above script is located in /var/www/html/Test which I am including using include_once'Test/test.php';

Comment: Proper way would be to use config file, where relative path to folder is specified. Hardcoding absolute paths is never great idea.
The fact that this is test script you could just use `/var/www/html/uploaded`, without using $_SERVER variable.

Comment: I have tried without DOCUMENT_ROOT using only first move_uploaded_file statement but had no successes.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but and found solution to be:

```
chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/aitech/images/passport_photos
```

Where `/opt/lampp/htdocs/php/aitech/images/passport_photos`  is the path to the folder I intend to upload to.